# I want to store different categories of data in the 1 gb text file??(data in the sense,Input data(Plain text))I want to store that and access it

Tags: python

Our project is to make Discussion Forum like stack overflow web site.But it is a command line application in python.We have to use only text file of 1 gigabyte space to store all the information(I do not want to use outer dependencies).Our discussion forum contains 6 categories. so i had got an idea that If i divide the file into blocks then i can store the each categories data in each block.If i store like that how to access it.if i went wrong lead me to the correct way please and be fast.

Comment: Any code? What do you have so far?

Comment: No we had a constraint that not to use database.@AshwiniChaudhary

Comment: @user1922399 "if i went wrong lead me to the correct way" - So as Ashwini mentioned, correct way is to use a database.

Comment: @PeterVaro I tried to keep delimiter at the start index and end of the each index using seek() function. If i do like that ,from start to end it is reading whole data as a single line 
My code:
f=open("test1.txt",'wb')
f.write("@users@") 
u_space=100*1024*1024
f.seek((u_space)-14) 
f.write("@users@\n")

I don't want to use database. :(

Comment: I understand the reasons to not use a database. @user1022399 said verbosely that database is not an option. I guess he is expecting tips for search lookup on large file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create one more file for index - for quick access to specific post. The index entry should have constant length in bytes and entries should be sorted for fast lookup. For each entry in index file you need: unique identifier, offset (to simply do good old fseek on data file), and length of post. Because there will be no complex search performed on data file, just fseek X bytes and read Y bytes, you can safely have each post compressed (e.g. with gzip) in data file.

Another thing you have to consider - are the posts likely to change or are they immutable after posted? If they can be changed/edited/deleted, you have to implement defragmenting and reindexing of data file, because:

1. Length of specific post may get increased, requiring to shift all the posts stored after it.
2. Length of specific post may get decreased, leaving small gap in data file.
3. Post may be deleted, leaving big gap in data file.

It is up to you to choose strategy:

1. Growing post may be left in place, triggering immediate shift of posts stored after it and at least partial reindexing OR it may be moved to the end of the file, temporarily leaving a gap on it's former location.
2. Gaps may be removed by defragmenting and reindexing immediately or this task can be scheduled regularly.

About 6 categories of your forum: Category can be distinguished by first 3 bits (can distinguish max. 8 categories) or more safely 4 bits (max. 16 categories). Constant length of blocks in data file is not a good idea because categories are likely to hold very different amount of content. Furthermore it doesn't really help much in lookup.